# php Function parameter which changes a given value

Tags: php

I am new to php and I am trying to do the following task. My task is to complete the missing code. Can any one help me why the function is not returning what I wanted it to return and any suggestions on how I can restructure my code will be appreciated. as I mentioned I am not allowed to change the given partial code. **Assignment**:  Your task is to complete the below program so that it prints as shown in the example. There's only one missing function that you need to write. Just write that missing function in the text box. Incomplete program.

```
    <?php



    // Your code here



    $charstring = "first\n";

    newvalue($charstring);

    echo "String in the end: $charstring\n";



?>

Example output


String in the start: first
String in the end: New string
```

**My code:**

```
function newvalue($charstring){
 global $charstring;
 echo "String in the start: $charstring";
 return "New string";
}
```

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970613/variable-in-php

Comment: I think it's called pass-by-reference...`&$charstring`

Comment: I just need suggestions if I am approaching the task wrong or missing some thing? Is it wrong to ask sir?

Comment: You can see a few examples in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, you must update the `$charstring` variable and then return it

```
<?php
 function newvalue($charstring){

 global $charstring;

echo "String in the start: $charstring <br />"; 
//If you are using a browswer, you must use a <br /> tag to get a new line,
// if you aren't using a browser than remove it

$charstring = "New String";

return $charstring;
}

$charstring = "first\n";

newvalue($charstring);

echo "String in the end: $charstring\n";
/*  
Example output

String in the start: first
String in the end: New string

*/
?>
```